# Shiny : icon doesn't appears as expected

Tags: r, shiny

This code open a modal in order to deal with some data. In this modal there is an icon("minus") rendering fine.

In the main UI below the "Modal" button, I print a text "Hello" with an icon but this icon doesn't appears.

If I click on the "Modal" button, the modal opens AND the icon appears in the main window ! I have the same behavior with Firefox or Chrome...

Do you have an explanation to this strange behavior and a tip to deal with ?

Thanx

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  actionButton("open", "Modal"),
  uiOutput("myicon")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  myvals <- reactiveVal(
    data.frame(item=c(1,2,3),value=c("value1","value2","value3"))
  )
  
  output$myicon <- renderUI({
    to_print <- paste0("Hello ",icon("circle-check"))
    HTML(to_print)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$open, {
    showModal(
      modalDialog(
        tagList(
          div(id="choice")
        ),
        footer = tagList(
          modalButton("cancel"),
          actionButton("save", "SAVE")
        )
      )
    )
    add_items()
  })
  
  add_items <- function() {
    lapply(1:nrow(myvals()), function(row) {
      insertUI(selector = "#choice", ui = add_item(row, myvals()[row,]$item, myvals()[row,]$value))
      observeEvent(input[[paste0("bu",row)]], {
        removeUI(selector = paste0("#choice",row))
        runjs(paste0("Shiny.onInputChange('",paste0("item",row),"',null)"))
        runjs(paste0("Shiny.onInputChange('",paste0("value",row),"',null)"))
      })
    }
    )
  }
  
  add_item <- function(row, item, value) {
    return(
      tagList(
        div( id=paste0("choice",row),
             actionButton(inputId = paste0("bu",row), icon("minus")),
             div(textInput(inputId = paste0("item",row), "ID", value=item)),
             div(textInput(inputId = paste0("value",row), "Value",value=value))
        )
      )
    )
  }
  
  observeEvent(input$save, {
    for (i in 1:3) {
      print(paste("item=", input[[paste0("item",i)]], "value=", input[[paste0("value",i)]]))
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues.

First `circle-check` might not available with the fontawesome version your shiny version is using. Try `check` instead.

Second, `icon()` returns already HTML. It is not a good idea to convert that into a character vector using `paste()`. Use `span()` instead and wrap `icon()` in it.

```r
  output$myicon <- renderUI({
    span("Hello ", icon("check"))
  })
```

Full app:

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  actionButton("open", "Modal"),
  uiOutput("myicon")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  myvals <- reactiveVal(
    data.frame(item=c(1,2,3),value=c("value1","value2","value3"))
  )
  
  output$myicon <- renderUI({
    span("Hello ", icon("check"))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$open, {
    showModal(
      modalDialog(
        tagList(
          div(id="choice")
        ),
        footer = tagList(
          modalButton("cancel"),
          actionButton("save", "SAVE")
        )
      )
    )
    add_items()
  })
  
  add_items <- function() {
    lapply(1:nrow(myvals()), function(row) {
      insertUI(selector = "#choice", ui = add_item(row, myvals()[row,]$item, myvals()[row,]$value))
      observeEvent(input[[paste0("bu",row)]], {
        removeUI(selector = paste0("#choice",row))
        runjs(paste0("Shiny.onInputChange('",paste0("item",row),"',null)"))
        runjs(paste0("Shiny.onInputChange('",paste0("value",row),"',null)"))
      })
    }
    )
  }
  
  add_item <- function(row, item, value) {
    return(
      tagList(
        div( id=paste0("choice",row),
             actionButton(inputId = paste0("bu",row), icon("minus")),
             div(textInput(inputId = paste0("item",row), "ID", value=item)),
             div(textInput(inputId = paste0("value",row), "Value",value=value))
        )
      )
    )
  }
  
  observeEvent(input$save, {
    for (i in 1:3) {
      print(paste("item=", input[[paste0("item",i)]], "value=", input[[paste0("value",i)]]))
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you, the paste0 was the issue...but circle-check and circle-xmark works well in Shiny

Comment: @Fabrice: Interesting! In my case neither `circle-check` nor `circle-xmark` work, probably  depends on the fontawesome version of the fontawesome R package which is installed. I'm running shiny 1.6 and fontawesome 0.5.0.

Comment: My R/packages versions are : R version 4.2.2, fontawesome_0.5.0 and shiny_1.7.4

Comment: @Fabrice: Ok, then it is the shiny version, which uses a new fontawesome version!